# Website forces user to click back button quickly and repeatedly to go back

Tags: html, web

So I built a website that provides link to an external website. On the external website, when the user tries to go back, it won't work unless the user **furiously** presses the back button multiple times. It's not a browser problem so my guess is that it's probably on the external website's side. The URL will switch to 'http://website.com/index.htm', with '/index.htm' at the end, then revert back to what it originally was. Would anyone know what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Basically, they have a redirect from their bare URL to the index.htm. When someone clicks back, it goes to the page with the redirect, and redirects them to the index.htm. If you change your link to the one with index.htm, no redirect is needed. Of course, you'll need to know if they change it to index.html or index.aspx or nothing at all...

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll try changing the URL then.